# I am getting an error connecting to IP (Socket failed: EPERM)

Tags: android, sockets, executorservice

I have trouble with connecting to a local web interface (192.168.10.13:3671) that are connected to my KNX network from the emulator/phone in `Android Studio`.
I've tried to connect to the same web interface with a already developed app called KNXwizard and that works, but I see in the code that that app uses `AsyncTask`.

Always getting this error: `Error creating KNXnet/IP tunneling link: tuwien.auto.calimero.KNXException: connecting from /192.168.163.198:3671 to /192.168.10.13:3671: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

I've checked this posts

[Socket failed 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266801/java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted)

[Socket failed 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722052/mqtt-service-error-socket-failed-eperm)

Tried everything there, added permissions to my `AndroidManifest.xml`, uninstalled, used physical phone etc. But nothing works.

It could be my code, I've tried searching for an alternative method for `AsyncTask`. So it could be that the code is written wrong. Hope someone could help me out.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static InetSocketAddress local = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.163.198", 3671);
private static InetSocketAddress server = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.13",
        KNXnetIPConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);





Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();




    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    //doInBackground
                    System.out.println("This example establishes a tunneling connection to the KNXnet/IP server " + server);

                    // A KNX tunneling link supports NAT (Network Address Translation) if required.
                    // We also indicate that the KNX installation uses twisted-pair (TP) medium, with TP1 being the most common.
                    // KNXNetworkLink is the base interface implemented by all supported Calimero links to a KNX network.
                    try (KNXNetworkLink knxLink = KNXNetworkLinkIP.newTunnelingLink(local, server, false, TPSettings.TP1)) {
                        System.out.println("Connection established to server " + knxLink.getName());
                        System.out.println("Close connection again");
                    } catch (KNXException | InterruptedException e) {
                        // KNXException: all Calimero-specific checked exceptions are subtypes of KNXException

                        // InterruptedException: longer tasks that might block are interruptible, e.g., connection procedures. In
                        // such case, an instance of InterruptedException is thrown.
                        // If a task got interrupted, Calimero will clean up its internal state and resources accordingly.
                        // Any deviation of such behavior, e.g., where not feasible, is documented in the Calimero API.

                        System.out.println("Error creating KNXnet/IP tunneling link: " + e);

                    }
                }


            });
        }


    });
}
```

Comment: What api level are you testing on?

Comment: `android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"`

Comment: Just because you're using Android Studio to develop your app and start an AVD doesn't mean that it's Android Studio itself that's performing the connection. The AVD emulator is actually a part of the standard Android SDK, Android Studio just provides a nice GUI over the top of it. If you want, you can follow the advice in [this article](https://medium.com/michael-wallace/how-to-install-android-sdk-and-setup-avd-emulator-without-android-studio-aeb55c014264) to install the SDK and setup an AVD without using Android Studio.

Comment: `I have trouble with connecting to a web server....` Please edit your post and inform us right away where your server is running on. You can also delete some comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
It was a stupid mistake with the IP address, should have seen that before. I just change the IP address to that I have on the phone I was connected to (192.168.10.15).